# I've user_birthday, but FQL returns NULL in birthday result

Tags: facebook, symfony, facebook-fql

This is my Facebook UID: 1053557928. If I run this FQL in the explorer, I get results I expect. To be more precise, I get exactly the "birthday" field. I have the correct permission "user_birthday".

```
SELECT uid, birthday, name        
FROM user        
WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 
  FROM friend 
  WHERE uid1='1053557928'
) limit 3
```

If I run same query from a Symfony2 command console, I get the results, but no the field birthday. I am sure to have permissions.

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
    array(3) {
      'uid' =>
      string(9) "0987654321234567890"
      'birthday' =>
      NULL
      'name' =>
      string(12) "Middle John"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(3) {
      'uid' =>
      string(9) "0987654321234567890"
      'birthday' =>
      NULL
      'name' =>
      string(15) "Short John"
    }
    [2] =>
    array(3) {
      'uid' =>
      string(9) "0987654321234567890"
      'birthday' =>
      NULL
      'name' =>
      string(12) "Long John"
   }
}
```

Also, if I try to execute:

```
    $accessToken = $this->container->getParameter('facebook_app_token');
    $uid1 = '1053557928';
    $wishInterval = new WishDates();
    $startSearchDate = clone $wishInterval->getDateFrom();
    $fqlDates = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        $month = $startSearchDate->format("F");
        $day = (int)$startSearchDate->format("d");
        if ($fqlDates != "") {
            $fqlDates .= " OR ";
        }
        $fqlDates .= " strpos(birthday, \"{$month} {$day},\")>=0";
        $startSearchDate->modify("+1 days");
    }
    $fql = "SELECT uid, birthday, name " .
        "       FROM user " .
        "       WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='$uid1') limit 3";


    // Interrogo Facebook
    $config = array(
        'appId' => $this->container->getParameter('facebook_app_id'),
        'secret' => $this->container->getParameter('facebook_client_secret'),
        'allowSignedRequest' => true
    );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $query = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => $fql,
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    );
    $return = $facebook->api($query);
```

I get "Requires user session". But I am logged in with Facebook. The query generated ($fql) still works fine in facebook explorer API. But this code returns array birthday. What happen?

Comment: is it possible that the date format for birthday that fql returns isn't the same format that your application expects.  e.g. a string vs a datetime object?

Comment: Nope, birthday is empty.

Comment: are you saying your results from fql are empty?

Comment: I am saying that birthday and birthday_date is null. You can see var_dump in my question.